# Finding the largest not-necessarily contiguous alternating binary string after inverting any sub-string from a given string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm having problems solving this problem within the time limit.

> **Alternative Thinking**
>    http://codeforces.com/contest/603/problem/A
>   Kevin has just recevied his disappointing results on the USA Identification of Cows Olympiad (USAICO) in the form of a binary string of length n. Each character of Kevin's string represents Kevin's score on one of the n questions of the olympiad—'1' for a correctly identified cow and '0' otherwise.
>   However, all is not lost. Kevin is a big proponent of alternative thinking and believes that his score, instead of being the sum of his points, should be the length of the longest alternating subsequence of his string. Here, we define an alternating subsequence of a string as a not-necessarily contiguous subsequence where no two consecutive elements are equal. For example, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, and {1, 0, 1, 0} are alternating sequences, while {1, 0, 0} and {0, 1, 0, 1, 1} are not.
>   Kevin, being the sneaky little puffball that he is, is willing to hack into the USAICO databases to improve his score. In order to be subtle, he decides that he will flip exactly one substring—that is, take a contiguous non-empty substring of his score and change all '0's in that substring to '1's and vice versa. After such an operation, Kevin wants to know the length of the longest possible alternating subsequence that his string could have.
>   **Input**
>   The first line contains the number of questions on the olympiad n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000).
>   The following line contains a binary string of length n representing Kevin's results on the USAICO.
>   **Output**
>   Output a single integer, the length of the longest possible alternating subsequence that Kevin can create in his string after flipping a single substring.

**My Code**
A little explanation: I try every substring and invert that, then I find the longest alternating substring by taking every first occuring 0 and 1. 'f' is the value 0 or 1 which I'm finding, which alternates. I try f=0 and 1 both for index=0 for the string for which we are calculating the score. e.g. the score for 10011101001100001 will be calculated by **10**0**1**11**010**0**1**1**0**000**1**, i.e. 9.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem_A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        final String str = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        int maxScore = score(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                String str2 = invert(str, i, j);
                int score = score(str2);
                if (score > maxScore) {
                    maxScore = score;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxScore);
    }

    private static int score(String str) {
        char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
        int finalScore = 0;
        for (int f = 0; f < 2; f++) {
            int fval = f;
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < chArr.length; i++) {
                if (chArr[i] - '0' == f) {
                    score++;
                    f = 1 - f;
                }
            }
            if (score > finalScore) {
                finalScore = score;
            }
            f = fval;
        }
        return finalScore;
    }

    private static String invert(String str, int i, int j) {
        char[] chArr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            chArr[k] = (char) (1 - chArr[k] + 2 * '0');
        }
        return new String(chArr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The score is equal to the number of *edges*, that is transitions from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0. After flipping number of edges *inside* the flipped range remains unchanged. Flipping may add two extra edges on the range boundaries; for that you need to find two occurrences of `11` or `00` and make the range to flip just one digit in each.

For example,

```
    100101001
      ^^^^^
    101010101
```

Of course there are some corner cases to be considered.